# Using point-to-point VPN doesn't seem to use the correct network interface

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, vpn, pptp

I've just subscribed to a VPN service (PureVPN), and setup correctly the point-to-point settings in network manager.

[image: PPTP config]

Now if I go on a website to check my IP address, it still show my usual public IP address (2404:e800:e622:789:b5bd:51e:fe3b:1770).

I've checked my ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:0e:a1:54:70:c6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1071469 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1071469 (1.0 MB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:136.0.6.62  P-t-P:136.0.6.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          RX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:4636 (4.6 KB)  TX bytes:4701 (4.7 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:27:37:64:03:a6  
          inet addr:192.168.0.15  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7af3:1eee:6abe:6315/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2404:e800:e622:789:34f2:6622:3f06:cbf8/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2404:e800:e622:789:b5bd:51e:fe3b:1770/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:178921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:95588
          TX packets:116198 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:178670255 (178.6 MB)  TX bytes:14711282 (14.7 MB)
          Interrupt:17
```

And my routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     50     0        0 ppp0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
136.0.6.2       192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
136.0.6.5       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ppp0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlan0
```

I would expect all the traffic to go through ppp0, but it seems that it is not the case, everything still goes through wlan0.

Is there something I am missing?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Your VPN provider is only providing IPv4 connectivity via the VPN, while your ISP is providing both IPv4 and IPv6.  When IPv6 is available (both you and the remote website have IPv6 support), your machine will prefer an IPv6 path over an IPv4 path.  If you want to force all traffic over the VPN, you will probably have to disable IPv6 on your machine.  Or check if your VPN provider has support for configuring IPv6 over the PtP link.

Comment: In addition: If you want to debug IPv6, you should look at the IPv6 tables: So use `route -6` or `ip -6 route show`.

Comment: Thanks, so I've added these 3 lines in my /etc/sysctl.conf: 
`net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1`
Then did `sysctl -p` to have IPv6 disabled.
The thing is that this setting doesn't last after a restart, e.g. if I do `service network-manager restart`, I've got the IPv6 coming back again.
And if I do `sysctl -p` while connected to the VPN, then it works fine. However, if I disable IPv6 and then try to connect to the VPN, I can't reach any host, so this is really confusing